# Problems with mscorelib? : System.ArgumentException

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0, argumentexception, mscorlib

i have a Asp.Net web application, and in VisualStudio it works perfect.
i published the project to my server, and when i run it on the server, i get an System.ArgumentException

[image: This is the error page]

in the **details**, there is written :

> Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): mscorlib.

does this mean that there are problems with mscorelib?
and how do i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This means that you have duplicate sessionState section or its subsection in your `web.config`.

> Key duplication when adding: sessionState

Comment: i don't get it. why does it work perfect in visual studio then? in VS it doesn't give an error

Comment: I don't get it either, if you host it on mono, they have presumably fixed this bug already http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.10.2

Comment: how can i try to fix it?

Comment: Which version do you use?

Comment: asp.net 2.0 and mono 2.11.1-0055. do you want to see my web.config??

Comment: That won't help. Sounds like a bug in mono, already submitted and people struggle with it. Someone suggests that this happens when connections are made when the site is not fully initialized and thus initialization occurs multiple times. https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=667329

Comment: it is fixed. i did search in my web.config for duplicated things and i saw that my system.web was double. Still thanks for your help!